# GPU on P2 instance slower than MacBook (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow

Just launched an AWS P2 instance to train this DNC: https://github.com/Mostafa-Samir/DNC-tensorflow (I've updated the code to tensorflow 1.8 standards).

Training on my Macbook is about twice as fast as training it on the GPU - I'm not sure why this is the case. I've checked whether TF on the instance is executing operations on the GPU, and it is

EDIT (More details):
Measuring execution execution time over 2500 iterations. On Macbook it took around 20mins, on AWS around 40mins

Comment: You have one powerful MacBook then. Jokes aside: you may want to add some details, like what you measured, how long that 'twice' was (seconds? hours), if the data was local, and so on.

Comment: This particular model is not GPU friendly at all. You may want to try it on a `c5.xlarge` instance, it may yield better result.

Comment: @Kh40tiK c5.xlarge is still slower than on macbook CPU :S

Comment: I'm facing this problem, too. Like @Kh40tiK said, the model seems not GPU friendly. Although I used [DeepMind's DNC implementation](https://github.com/deepmind/dnc), AFAIK, the problem could be attributed to computing the gradients of several reduce_prod's in the CPU instead of GPU. Now I'm tracking [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8841), if your case happens to have the same cause, help us promote the feature request.